How to display a private field in the Unity Inspector as read-only
I’m working on a Unity project and I have a private field in one of my scripts that I’d like to display in the Unity Inspector. However, I want to ensure that this field is read-only and cannot be modified from the Inspector, just like private fields appear in Debug mode?
Below is a picture showing a private field in Debug mode.

It can be a package, a custom editor, or anything else.

[HideInInspector] <-- try this?

[HideInInspector] only hides your variable and you cannot see it in the editor.

There already are hundreds of solutions for this ...

One way to solve it is creating a custom PropertyAttributes/Drawer, like this one:
PropertyAttribute:
using UnityEngine;

public class DisplayWithoutEdit : PropertyAttribute
{
}

PropertyDrawer:
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(DisplayWithoutEdit))]
public class DisplayWithoutEditDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label, true);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}

Use it like:
[SerializeField, DisplayWithoutEdit] private int variable = 2;


Have you tried your answer? According to my testing, non serialized fields do not run their PropertyDrawers at all.

Here it is! Thanks, man.

@shingo If it's a private field, you need to use the SerializeField attribute, but I'm satisfied with it.

@나만없어고양이 If you use the SerializeField attribute, the field becomes changeable in the debug mode.

@shingo I didn’t know that. Are there any issues that might arise if it’s editable in Debug Mode?

@나만없어고양이 This means that its initial value may no longer be the default value seen in the code.

I forgot the [SerializeField] attribute on the original answer, updated :D
